# Justify differentiability for a parametric function

Tags: calculus

> Let $\gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \Bbb R^3$ be
>   $$\gamma(t)=(4t,\cos(3t),\sin(3t)).$$
>
> Justify that $\gamma$ is differentiable.

This is a question of a past Analysis exam and I do not know how to go about it. All the information I have found in the internet is about finding a derivative of a parametric function whose codomain is $\Bbb R^2$.

My question is: How do I show that this function is differentiable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each of the components are differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector valued function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable if its component functions $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable. Here, $n=1$ and $m=3$. The component functions are,

$$f_1(t) = 4t\\
f_2(t)=\cos(3t)\\
f_3(t)=\sin(3t)
$$

Hopefully it is clear that each of these component functions are differentiable. Then, we have that $f$ is differentiable and its derivative is the Jacobian (matrix of partial derivatives),

$$
\nabla f = \begin{pmatrix}
  \partial_t f_1 \\
  \partial_t f_2 \\
  \partial_t f_3 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  4 \\
  -3\sin(3t) \\
  3\cos(3t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yes, it is clear to me that the components are differentiable, thanks